# Run MonDevelop gtk# program without mono runtime terminal showing - Ubuntu

Tags: c#, ubuntu, mono, terminal, gtk#

When I compile my gtk# project with MonoDevelop, it creates the files and puts them in /bin/Release just as it should. But when I double click on the program, it shows the mono runtime terminal in the background. I want to be able to open my program without the runtime terminal showing as well. Is there anyway to accomplish this?

Note: This program is made only for use in Ubuntu.

Comment: Could not reproduce it on openSUSE 12.1. So added ubuntu tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's not the best way to double click on Mono assemblies on Linux..

You can try creating a simple executable script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
mono /path/to/executable.exe
```

Give it the executable permission, than try to execute it.

Comment: Thanks, runs with out the terminal now. But the title of the program in the top panel still shows "Mono Runtime (Terminal)" in Ubuntu 12.04. Is there a way to fix that as well?

Comment: Never mind, just /path/to/executable.exe without "mono" in front runs how I want. MonoDevelop + GTK + Ubuntu takes quite a bit of getting used to.